# Can i use windows 10 32bit OS on Acer Aspire 4720 if default 1GB RAM is increased to 2.5GB?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, 32-bit, acer-aspire

I am using Acer Aspire 4720(for more details click [here](http://www.miniputer.com/Acer/Aspire_4720.html)) which comes with a default 1GB RAM(512mbx2,dual channel).Laptop is 32bit architecture hardware.I tried using windows 10 32bit,but it's performance was bad.

I'm planning to buy 2GB RAM,so the laptop RAM becomes 2GB and 512MB(2GB+512MB).If laptop RAM is increased(2GB+512MB),can i then use windows 10 32bit on laptop?

Can Acer Aspire 4720 with increased RAM(2GB+512MB) run windows 10 32bit OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The min RAM for 32-bit Windows 10 is 1GB, after adding 2GB RAM, your memory has reached 2.5Gb, even meet 64-bit Windows 10. Therefore, it’s enough for 32-bit system.